# Unexpected "}" when pressing 'Cancel' in a linux dialog script

Tags: linux, shell, dialog, sh

I'm trying to figure out why I keep gettning an error `Unexpected }` when pressing cancel in the following dialog script.

I'm a complete noob when it comes to scripting.

```
#!/bin/sh
hdd=`fdisk -l | grep ^Disk | awk -F: "{ print $1 }"`
function dialog_menu {
    dialog --title "Disktest" --menu "$hdd" 16 60 7 \
    "badblocks -sv /dev/sda" "Read test on /dev/sda" \
    "badblocks -wsv /dev/sda" "Read/Write test on /dev/sda" \
    "badblocks -sv /dev/sdb" "Read test on /dev/sdb" \
    "badblocks -wsv /dev/sdb" "Read/Write test on /dev/sdb" \
    "badblocks -sv /dev/sdc" "Read test on /dev/sdc" \
    "badblocks -wsv /dev/sdc" "Read/Write test on /dev/sdc" \
    Exit "Exit disk test" 2>~/tmp ;

menuitem=`cat ~/tmp`
opt=$?

case $menuitem in
    "badblocks -sv /dev/sda") var=`badblocks -sv /dev/sda`;
    read;
dialog_menu ;;
    "badblocks -wsv /dev/sda") var=`badblocks -wsv /dev/sda`;
    read;
dialog_menu ;;
    "badblocks -sv /dev/sdb") var=`badblocks -sv /dev/sdb`;
    read;
dialog_menu ;;
    "badblocks -wsv /dev/sdb") var=`badblocks -wsv /dev/sdb`;
    read;
dialog_menu ;;
    "badblocks -sv /dev/sdc") var=`badblocks -sv /dev/sdc`;
    read;
dialog_menu ;;
    "badblocks -wsv /dev/sdc") var=`badblocks -wsv /dev/sdc`;
    read;
dialog_menu ;;
    Exit) clear;
    echo "Usage: badblocks -[w]sv /dev/[DEVICE]";
    echo "$hdd";
exit;;
esac

clear
}
dialog_menu
rm ~/tmp
```

I'm greatful for any help I can get!

Comment: Ok, so I figured it out myself just after I sent this question in, and no, the } is supposed to be there since its the end of the function. I just added another "exit" line just after the esac line and it worked. Thanks anyway for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I figured it out myself just after I sent this question in, and no, the } is supposed to be there since its the end of the function. I just added another "exit" line just after the esac line and it worked. Thanks anyway for your help